# Echosign widget redirect to the next signer

Tags: php, echosign

I'm having issues on using widget on my PHP application. Upon creating the 
widget im storing this on my database to reference it later.

I'm able to show the widget on my page by using the javascript returned by calling this endpoint:
https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/widgets/_0

However, the problem arise when after the first signer signs a document and redirected back to my page. Calling the previous endpoint again to retrieve the javascript code and use it shows the same page for the first signer.

How can I retain the signature made by the first signer and move to the next signer?

Answer (score 1):

While creating the widget using [POST/widgets](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/widgets/) endpoint you can specify some counter signers in the request. Once a hosted widget has been signed by any signer, the counter signer will get a signing mail containing the agreement where the signature of the first signer will be retained and that agrement will be waiting for the signature of the counter signer.
You can see the request of [POST/widget](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v5#!/widgets/) to know how to specify counter signer in your request body.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add multiple signers on the same widget, you need to add them as countersigners. So, once the first signer signs, the next signer would get a mail with a link to sign. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: This works when creating agreements thru email but when using widget it doesn't.